# Sending variable value in __asm function for code injection

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, visual-c++, syntax

I want to hook a game function and inject my code in it's cave code, but when I try to send the value of my variables with the addresses I want to jump and return, it mess it up.

Example:

```
DWORD returnAddress = 0x12345678; //the static address in game that I have to return after my function

_declspec(naked) void asmfunc()
{
    __asm
    {
      ...
      jmp returnAddress //I already tried [returnAddress] with same result
    }
}
```

As you know, it sends the address of `returnAddress` in my process to the jmp instruction that will be converted in the target process address whose value has, obviously, nothing to do with mine.  I want to do a jmp to the game address 0x12345678 but if I do `jmp 0x12345678` the compiler accuses syntax error.

Of course it works fine with dll injection, but I want to do it with simple code injection. Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: Pro tip: don't write inline ASM in C++ programs, *at all*.

Comment: @JesperJuhl so what's the best approach to inject assembly code in a target process in your opinion?

Comment: Tried `jmp dword ptr [returnAddress]`?

Comment: @user253751 yeah, same behavior.

Comment: Can someone explain me why the question was downvoted?

Comment: @EduardoM "so what's the best approach to inject assembly code in a target process in your opinion?" - finding a way to avoid having to do it in the first place.

Comment: Oh wait, I see now. You don't even *have* the variable `returnAddress` in the target process, so you can't read that. You have to put the actual number in the assembly code. I suggest you stop trying to use C for this. Learn basic assembly and machine code and build your own jump instruction.

Comment: @user253751 Yeah, that's why it works only via dll injection. My workaround was to inject the raw shellcode in the process, but I thought there was a more elegant way to do it. Seems like this is a VS compiler limitation.

Comment: Use immediate values that are part of the machine code you inject

Comment: @EduardoM I think it's just a limitation of how assemblers work. They aren't designed to make code that changes itself at runtime.